# Is there a javascript grid that can read csv format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, import

Is there a javascript framework with a grid widget that can directly import data in csv with a line of keys followed by lines of data?

"key1","key2","key3"
1,2,3
2,4,6
3,6,9

I'm using jqgrid and I have to convert everything to a key:value format like this:

"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":3,...
The problem is that for large arrays the time it takes to do these conversions is significant and sometimes enough to timeout the script.  I'm wondering if dojo or others would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

I think this jQuery plugin should suit you : http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/

There is an example at: http://code.google.com/p/js-tables/wiki/Table